# Align clocks horizontally on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want clocks displaying different time zones on a webpage that i am designing.For this,i have embedded the javascript files from a webiste called qlock.The HTML code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
qlock_city_name="Adelaide";
qlock_gmt_offset=9.5;
qlock_bg_color="#000000";
qlock_text_color="#ffffff";
qlock_dst_week1=1;
qlock_dst_dow1=7;
qlock_dst_month1=10;
qlock_dst_week2=1;
qlock_dst_dow2=7;
qlock_dst_month2=4;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qlock.com/live/qlock.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
qlock_city_name="Melbourne";
qlock_gmt_offset=10;
qlock_bg_color="#000000";
qlock_text_color="#ffffff";
qlock_dst_week1=1;
qlock_dst_dow1=7;
qlock_dst_month1=10;
qlock_dst_week2=1;
qlock_dst_dow2=7;
qlock_dst_month2=4;
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qlock.com/live/qlock.js"></script>
```

What this does is display the clocks of Adelaide and Melbourne one below the other.
Is there any way to display them horizontally right next to each other?

Comment: There's not much HTML in there. That's javascript.

Comment: wrap them in div and float to left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDxTA/1/)**

Wrap the clock with div and give the float to it

```
<div class="left"><script type="text/javascript">
qlock_city_name="Adelaide";
qlock_gmt_offset=9.5;
qlock_bg_color="#000000";
qlock_text_color="#ffffff";
qlock_dst_week1=1;
qlock_dst_dow1=7;
qlock_dst_month1=10;
qlock_dst_week2=1;
qlock_dst_dow2=7;
qlock_dst_month2=4;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qlock.com/live/qlock.js"></script>
    </div>
<div class="left">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
qlock_city_name="Melbourne";
qlock_gmt_offset=10;
qlock_bg_color="#000000";
qlock_text_color="#ffffff";
qlock_dst_week1=1;
qlock_dst_dow1=7;
qlock_dst_month1=10;
qlock_dst_week2=1;
qlock_dst_dow2=7;
qlock_dst_month2=4;
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qlock.com/live/qlock.js"></script>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Your second left `div` is not closed.

Comment: This works perfectly fine..However,I have  7 clocks to be displayed and after the 3rd clock,the next four are displayed in the next line..how can I force all 7 of them to be displayed in 1 single horizontal line

Comment: you must have set the fixed width for the container where you are displaying this clocks.. tats why after overflowing they displayed in next line. Try setting more width to the parent container.

Comment: There is no parent container..the code is exactly as you have suggested..only 4 more iterations of the above lines each wrapped in the div that you have suggested..

Comment: No i am not talking about my code, you have my code right, and you put that somewhere in your webpage, so you have to see how much space is available in the webpage so 7 clock can fit into it.

Answer (score 1):

you could set a css property on your clocks to float left

```
#qlock1, #qlock2{
    float: left;
}
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/kzf9R/)

P.S. you could set a common class for all clocks and not worry about every id in your css

Answer (score 0):

My way would be to place the scripts inside a simple table;

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:600px;">
  <tr height="30">
    <td width="150"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
qlock_city_name="Melbourne";
qlock_gmt_offset=10;
qlock_bg_color="#000000";
qlock_text_color="#ffffff";
qlock_dst_week1=1;
qlock_dst_dow1=7;
qlock_dst_month1=10;
qlock_dst_week2=1;
qlock_dst_dow2=7;
qlock_dst_month2=4;
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qlock.js"></script>
</td>
    <td width="200"><script type="text/javascript">
qlock_city_name="Adelaide";
qlock_gmt_offset=9.5;
qlock_bg_color="#000000";
qlock_text_color="#ffffff";
qlock_dst_week1=1;
qlock_dst_dow1=7;
qlock_dst_month1=10;
qlock_dst_week2=1;
qlock_dst_dow2=7;
qlock_dst_month2=4;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qlock.js"></script>
</td>
    <td width="250">CSS table layout cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe so yet @Amistad wanted to have 7 clocks horizontally aligned. The table method allows this to be done more systematically than via CSS floats.